# How to integrate a Google Docs document in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, google-docs, google-docs-api, liferay-6

Is there any way that we can integrate Google Docs in Liferay? I found some other 3rd party APIs, like Zoho, but I would like to use Google Docs instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be, you cat sync google docs with the server by some tools like here

> http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/187184/google_docs_desktop_app_available_now.html

and then you can sync this desktop folder with liferay

> http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-sync/features

Comment: I don't want to use any tool for this. Actually I am able to display the sheet in liferay by publishing the Sheet from Google Docs. It provide me the url with iframe but i am not able to edit it. It just displaying the stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a hook that uses the Google Docs' API.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 7.2 DXP now available with Google Doc(Online Document Editing).

Check this : https://www.liferay.com/products/dxp/new